# How do you add JS resources in eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, html

I have created a javascript file on my computer, and I wanted to put it in a web page. I used this html file to hold the code, with an src to load the processing js library that I had based my script on:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
            <title>Processing JS</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script src = "C:/Users/RandomNameAlphabetically:-)/Desktop/processing.js></script>
        </body>
    <html>
```

When I loaded this page in Google Chrome, it had an error that it could not load processing.js. Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Don't store your JavaScript file on your desktop. Put it in the same directory (or a child directory) as your HTML file and link to it as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[yourFileName].js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried, but in eclipse, it didn't work. Maybe there is also a backup folder I had to put the file in as well as the project folder.

Comment: It couldn't find the file when I moved it into the project folder

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like this is an Eclipse question.

First, Eclipse creates a workspace.  Eclipse's default workspace on Windows is something like C:\Users\[userID]\Eclipse\

Then you create projects of code in that workspace.  You can have many projects in one workspace.

It is easy for you to create multiple workspaces, too.  Projects in one workspace will not be visible in another.

You need to open up Windows Explorer and copy your JavaScript file from the desktop and paste it into the project in the workspace to be able to see and use it in your code.

Comment: I did, but the program couldn't find it (according to "inspect element")